# What does the discovery of Higgs boson mean for steady state theory?

Tags: cosmology, higgs

The relationship between the steady state theory and the notion of Higgs boson is not clear to me. What does the discovery of Higgs boson mean for steady state theory? Or are the two ideas purely orthogonal?

Comment: This question implies that someone has suggested that there is a "relationship between the steady state theory and the notion of Higgs boson". I've never heard of anyone claiming this. Do you have a reference to such a statement?

Comment: @Warrick, no, the question does not imply that. (See the last sentence in my question.)

Comment: Reason for downvotes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If by "steady state theory" you mean the [cosmological theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steady_State_theory) that explains the expansion of the universe using the creation of new matter: that is entirely unrelated to the Higgs boson. It has also been effectively disproven. Naturally, the discovery of the Higgs does not change that.